# How to execute script only when screen width is >1250px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
            $("#navbar").css({"height":"10vh"});
            $("#logo").css({"height":"4.5vh"});
            $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"4vh"});
            $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"7vh"});
            $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2vh"});
        }
        else{
            $("#navbar").css({"height":"14vh"});
            $("#logo").css({"height":"8vh"});
            $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"5.6vh"});
            $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"10vh"});
            $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2.4vh"});
        }
    })
})
```

It changes navigator when you are not on the top of site. I also wan't to make my site responsive and I changed the way that nav looks when width of screen is >1250px. I dont know how to stop executing this code when screen is smaller. I've tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).width() > 1250){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
                $("#navbar").css({"height":"10vh"});
                $("#logo").css({"height":"4.5vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"4vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"7vh"});
                $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2vh"});
            }
            else{
                $("#navbar").css({"height":"14vh"});
                $("#logo").css({"height":"8vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"5.6vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"10vh"});
                $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2.4vh"});
            }
        else{
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
                $("#navbar").css({"height":"10vh"});
                $("#logo").css({"height":"4.5vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"4vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"7vh"});
                $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2vh"});
            }
            else{
                $("#navbar").css({"height":"10vh"});
                $("#logo").css({"height":"4.5vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"top":"4vh"});
                $("#navbar-content").css({"right":"7vh"});
                $("#navbar-content a").css({"font-size":"2vh"});
            }
        }
    })
})
```

It works untill I scroll little bit down. Then it won't work.

Comment: consider using class names and media queries - will make it alot easier to maintain and troubleshoot.

Comment: This -- scroll to the bottom to see class changes based on screen width https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: `@media (device-width >  12500px) { style content }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `window.matchMedia` function.

Use it like this to determine the screen size before executing a specific block of code:

```js
if (matchMedia('(min-width: 1250px)').matches) {
    // do stuff for over 1250 pixels
}
```